# Binding Images Url Array to Custom Image Control Property

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, custom-controls

I need to change images on mouseover after x amount of time, if there are multiple images are present in the list.

To achieve this i have developed a custom image control,  and my control has two properties basically MainImageSource which is a BitmapImage and ImageUrl which is a IList.

Now what am i doing here is onmouseenter starts a timer and change `MainImageSource` to the next image in the list (if there is any) after timer hass elapsed and reseting image onmouseleave event.

Everything's working fine, like when i set the imageurls it setups the images as expected.

Now i need to use this control in ListBox which is data bind to ObservableCollection of type `FileItem` (custom class). Now in listbox i need to setup that array so what i did was, add a property in `FileItem` called `Imageurls` of type `string[]`.
In xaml i used the following to data bind.

```
<local:MBImage ImageUrl="{Binding ImageUrls}"  Source="{Binding MainImageSource}" />
```

But ImageUrl of `MBImage` was never set.

So now there are two things

1. How can i bind `ImageUrls` of `FileItem` with `ImageUrl` of `MBImage`.
2. How can i get rid of `Source="{Binding MainImageSource}"`. As it is used internally within `MBImage`. And if i dont use MainImageSource Property it does not change the image even if i updated MBImage `Source`.

Add to everything is there a better way to achieve my main objective which was to show multiple images on hover. I am willing to rewrite everything if i find a better approach than this and which uses more of WPF's strengths.

**Edited**

This is the error

```
'ImageUrls' property not found on 'object' ''MBImage' (Name='')'
```

Which shows its looking for ImageUrls in MBImage rather than listbox itemsource of ObservableCollection  type.

MBImage.cs

```
class MBImage : Image, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<BitmapImage> bmpImages = new List<BitmapImage>();
    private Timer imgChangeTimer = new Timer(1000);
    private int curImage = 0;

    BitmapImage _MainImageSource = null;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageUrlProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ImageUrl", typeof(IList<string>), typeof(MBImage));

    public IList<string> ImageUrl
    {
        get { return (IList<string>)this.GetValue(ImageUrlProperty); }
        set
        {                
            this.SetValue(ImageUrlProperty, value);
            DownloadImages();
        }
    }

    public MBImage()
    {
        imgChangeTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(imgChangeElapsed);
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public BitmapImage MainImageSource
    {
        get
        {
            return _MainImageSource;
        }
        set
        {
            _MainImageSource = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MainImageSource");
        }
    }

    private void DownloadImages()
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += (s, e) =>
        {
            List<ImageDownloadArgs> argList = new List<ImageDownloadArgs>();

            int index = (int)e.Argument;
            int count = 1;
            if (index == -1)
            {
                count = ImageUrl.Count();
                index = 1;
            }

            for (int i = index; i < count; i++)
            {
                ImageDownloadArgs args = new ImageDownloadArgs();
                args.Index = i;


                Uri uri = new Uri(ImageUrl[i], UriKind.Absolute);

                using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
                {
                    webClient.Proxy = null;  
                    webClient.CachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.Default);
                    try
                    {
                        byte[] imageBytes = null;

                        imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(uri);

                        if (imageBytes == null)
                        {
                            e.Result = null;
                            return;
                        }
                        MemoryStream imageStream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
                        args.Img = new BitmapImage();

                        args.Img.BeginInit();
                        args.Img.StreamSource = imageStream;
                        args.Img.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                        args.Img.EndInit();

                        args.Img.Freeze();
                        imageStream.Close();

                        argList.Add(args);

                    }
                    catch (WebException)
                    {                
                        //argList.Add(args);
                    }
                }
            }
            e.Result = argList;
        };

        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            List<ImageDownloadArgs> argList = e.Result as List<ImageDownloadArgs>;
            bool shouldDownloadRest = false;
            foreach (ImageDownloadArgs args in argList)
            {
                if (args != null)
                {
                    if (args.Index == 0)
                    {
                        MainImageSource = args.Img;
                        bmpImages.Add(args.Img);
                        shouldDownloadRest = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        bmpImages.Add(args.Img);
                    }
                }
            }

            worker.Dispose();
            if (shouldDownloadRest)
                worker.RunWorkerAsync(-1);

        };

        worker.RunWorkerAsync(0);

    }

    private void imgChangeElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Time out");
        MainImageSource = bmpImages[++curImage % bmpImages.Count()];

    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseEnter(System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        imgChangeTimer.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeave(System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        imgChangeTimer.Stop();
        MainImageSource = bmpImages[0];
        curImage = 0;

    }
}
```

Comment: are you getting any binding errors?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out just edited the post with error.

Comment: can you post your complete xaml? also your MBImage

Comment: I dont know what part of xaml you want to see because there are loads of different stuff going on in there like this image is a part of listbox item and it has many controls in there. And i have already posted xaml part related to MBImage. And now have added MBImage.cs, but i am not liking this approach have just start working with wpf, i there must be a better way to do this. You can have a look and suggest me if you get some idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are `Setting the DataContext of MBImage to itself` in its constructor `DataContext = this;`, which you should not be doing. That is the reason it is searching in itself for properties when you do `ImageUrl="{Binding ImageUrls}"`

Remove `DataContext = this;` this line as it is not required.

Also I see that you are doing some work in the property setter, this will not be called from the Xaml bindings as wpf internally calls GetValue and SetValue functions.. if you want to do somethign on property value set, register the ValueChanged callback in the dependency property metadata while defining it and do that work in the valuechanged handler

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageUrlProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ImageUrl", typeof(IList<string>), typeof(MBImage), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, ImageUrlsChanged));
```

Comment: I dont see errors now, but still ImageUrl setter is never called